# What does this statement mean?

Tags: c

A foremention, the following is in a header file:

```
typedef struct{
   void*       userData;
} ESContext;
```

and, in the source file, there is the following structure:

```
typedef struct
{
   GLuint programObject;
} UserData;
```

So here goes.  In the same source file there is a function that begins as thus:

```
void Draw ( ESContext *esContext )
{
   UserData *userData = esContext->userData;
   ...
}
```

How does that last snip sound out vocally if you were to read it off?  What's it doing?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: "Make `userData` a pointer to `esContext`'s `userData`"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It assigns the pointer esContext->userData to the pointer userData.  The C language allows implicit cast between void pointers and pointers of any other type.

You might want to read the section of the [C FAQ relating to Pointers](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for answering this and for the FAQ link.  I hate having to choose best answers on this site for a lot of reasons.  Every one of these answers has been helpful.  Even's went into some of the detail that I needed:  "...assigned the value...."

Comment: Another reason I don't like playing favorites is because I don't know sometimes what the best answer is.  I wish the site didn't encourage the awarding of these medals.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a read at the [Clockwise Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). Not only will it help you understand how to put that statement into words that read nicely, but every other C statement too.

Answer (score 0):

`userData` is a pointer to a `UserData` that is assigned the value of the `userData` field of the struct that `esContext` points to.

```
UserData *userData = esContext->userData;
```

is equivalent to:

```
UserData *userData = (*esContext).userData;
```

Comment: But I'm just confused because, in the header file, the .userData member var itself is defined as a pointer to void.

Comment: The type of `esContext->userData` is a pointer to a void, which can be implicitly casted to any other type. What are you confused about?

Comment: I'm just confused because K&R would say that the esContext is the pointer and the userData following "->" is just the member of the structure.  But if the header file has userData as a *void, isn't this a pointer to a structure that contains a pointer member?

Comment: `userData` would be a pointer to a `UserData` struct. It is being assigned the value of the `userData` field of the struct that `esContext` points to, which is a pointer to a void. If the `userData` field in the `ESContext` struct was guaranteed to always be a `UserData` struct, you could just replace `void*` with `UserData*`.

Comment: You're saying that I can copy the _value_ of esContext's userData (that same userData member being a *void) with that statement? Not the address, but the value, of that userData member?

Comment: >"The value is a pointer." Okay. I just want to be absolutely certain that when everybody is talking about that field, that they remember its a pointer itself. Am I just basically reassigning that pointer?  Whatever that userData field pointed to, the UserData *userData on the left of the equation now points to?  That's all?

Comment: You aren't modifying the struct's value (the pointer), just assigning it to `userData`.

Comment: Thank you Evan for all your help.